# Reusage of deep frying oil and flour coated vegetables

Tags: indian-cuisine, deep-frying, cornstarch

I deep fry different mashed vegetables for various recipes. (For example, Indian Malai Kofta).
When I do so, I usually coat the vegetables in flour or corn flour, to prevent them from breaking in the oil. The problem is that afterwards the oil becomes tainted with the left over flour, changing the color of the oil, smell, and probably smoking point.

Is there any workaround to prevent this from happening? And is the oil still reusable if I use it within a few days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cool oil.  Filter through coffee filter.  Store in refrigerator.  You can reuse.  Heat oil to deep fry temp.  Fry a neutral piece of bread.  Taste.  You can reuse your oil as long as it doesn't impart an off taste to the bread.  My guess is that, in a stove top situation, you won't get more than one or two uses before the oil is degraded too much for frying.

Comment: What do you mean in a stovetop situation? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Just as a follow up to the comment - So do people who do regular deep frying actually each time use new oil? That probably triples at least the costs of the food.

Comment: By stove top situation, I mean that you don't have a commercial deep fryer.  Most home cooks put oil in a pot on the stove.  That means that the coating or other debris from your food sinks to the bottom of the oil, where it is hottest, and burns.  This degrades your oil rapidly.  In a commercial deep fryer, the oil is heated from the center (or slightly below) of the vat.  Debris falls to the cool zone in the bottom.  This, along with using higher quality frying oil, allows for the oil to be use repeatedly for a longer time.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refer this: http://whfoods.org/genpage.php?tname=dailytip&dbid=126

While reusing deep fried oil does not have drastic health effects, it does increase the concentration of saturated fats. If you are going to reuse, best thing to do is to use an oil with a high smoking point like pomace oil, mustard oil, cotton seed oil, rice bran. Absolutely do not deep fry in olive oil of any kind except pomace. While Canola is good ok to deep fry in, avoid re-using it.